# Sharepoint 2010 administrator with no administrator rights

Tags: 2010, permissions

I am new to SharePoint, I am using SharePoint 2010 and few weeks ago something went wrong.

I have virtual machine with SharePoint on it and the active directory of our company connected to it so all company accounts have access to SharePoint I've added my account to be administrator and in the beginning everything seem to work, I had full control can add users delete and so on.

But now I cant do this, when I go to Manage Service Applications I see the ribbon but all things in it are disabled I can't click them so I can't add new MMD or SSA.

Comment: could u check if the Administrator is added as Farm admin in (Security - Manage the farm administrators group ) in Central admin

Comment: yes it is and i still can't do enything from the ribbon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your account is in the Farm Administrators SharePoint group as indicated in Pushpendra's comment, are the service accounts used by the SharePoint Administrator and the Farm Administrator both in the local Administrators group on the server? Is your account in that local Admins group?  If not, are you able to try adding yourself to it?

Also in Central Admin, try going to Security->Service Accounts, select the Farm Account from the Credential Management dropdown and ensure it's pointing to the correct service account.

If those don't work, you can try running IE as an administrator: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1f92d977-400a-4d98-ab31-b01c5586d254/sharepoint-2010-server-farm-administrator-cannot-create-service-applications-and-web-applications?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Hope this helps.